# Commit modified files only using subversion

Tags: svn, unix, commit, ack, svncommit

I have a long list of commits to make and, as such, would like to stagger the commits. So, when I do:

> svn st | ack '^M'

I would like to commit these files *only*

Is this possible through the command line?

Comment: Just to clarify: you want to commit modified files only, and not those that were deleted, added, or replaced?

Comment: @malenkiy_scot Yes, I can confirm that I only want to commit *modified* files.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [xargs command](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xargs) is useful for this kind of thing.

Assuming you don't have any filenames containing space characters, you can do:

```
svn st | sed -n 's/^M//p' | xargs svn commit
```

If you do have space characters in filenames, the `sed` command becomes a little more complex, to add quotes around each filename:

```
svn st | sed -n 's/$/"/; s/^M */"/p' | xargs svn commit
```

(I'm not familiar with `ack` -- perhaps it could be also be used in place of `sed` in these examples)

Comment: If not -u or -v options are specified, the number of characters before the start of filename is known (it's 8), so sed can be simplified: svn st | grep '^M' | sed 's/.\{8\}\(.*\)/\1/' | xargs svn ci

Comment: All depends on your definition of "simple", I suppose ;-)

Comment: Excellent, the first example with sed worked well. I tried using ack, which is my preferred tool of choice normally, but I couldn't get it working. Thanks.